# Can’t get electron+webpack+webtorrent working

Tags: webpack, electron, webtorrent

We can’t get electron+webpack+webtorrent working. Webtorrent can’t connect to the tracker. It fails with “no port specified error”. Specifying `torrentPort` option removes error but doesn’t help to download the torrent’s files. Though webtorrent-desktop (without webpack) works. I found the difference as that working library detects TCPPool class present and uses it, so it can automatically assign torrentPort. An application built with webpack has it undefined. How to make it work?

Comment: For WebTorrent to work in electron with TCP peers, it must run in the Node.js process of electron, not the frontend process. You should check WebTorrent Desktop source code to check how we do it :)